# Going from 2 to 3 columns when expanding the width of screen

Tags: html, css

When my screen expands past a certain width I'd like to add another column to the unordered list items, from 2 columns to 3 columns. I'm not sure how I would do this? Bootstrap seems like it has the solution but I've never used it. Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eN9qM/

the html

```
<div class="sidebar">
   <div class="search-filters">Filters</div>
   <div class="search-results">
      <div class="listings">
         <ul>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Byebye</li>
            <li>Chuck</li>
            <li>Paul</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="listings-footer"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The css

```
.sidebar {
   position: fixed;
   top: 47px;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 60 % ;
   overflow - y: scroll;
   /*-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    background: #f7f7f7;*/
   background - color: aqua;
   /*border: 3px solid black;*/
}
   .search - filters {
      background - color: white;
      height: 40 % ;
}
   .search - results {
      padding: 10px 0 20px 20px;
      border: 3px solid black;
      height: 100 % ;
}
   .listings {
      border: 3px solid red;
      height: 100 % ;
}
   .listings - footer {
      border: 3px solid blue;
      /*height: 92px;
    height: 100%;*/
}
ul {
   /*width:100%;*/
   list - style - type: none;
   /*height: 100%;*/
   background - color: pink;
}
li {
   background: green;
   float: left;
   height: 250px;
   margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
   width: 45 % ;
}@
media(min - width: 1200px) {
   li {
      width: 25 % ;
   }
}
li: nth - child(even) {
   margin - right: 0;
}
```

Comment: so, to clarify, you're looking for the <li> items to be split up into either 2 or 3 columns, depending on screen size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the very right track with that media query. You only have to change the `width` inside it.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    li, li:nth-child(even) {
        width:30%;
        margin-right: 3.33%;
    }
}
```

([See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eN9qM/2/)) That means when the screen is at least 1200px wide, columns will occupy 30% of their container, plus 3.33% of right margin. I also overrode `li:nth-child(even)` so the second column will have right margin as well.

Bootstrap uses a [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) of 12 columns, where 12 columns means 100% of the parent's width. That is, if an element has class `col-lg-6 col-sm-3`, it means that in large (`lg`) screens, the element will have `width: 50%` (6 columns out of 12 total, that's 1/2), and in small (`sm`) screens, it will have `width: 25%` (3 columns out of 12 total, that's 1/4).

In your case, all your `li` elements should have class `col-lg-4 col-md-6`, which means it will take 1/3 of the parent's width in large screens and 1/2 in medium-width devices. (Large means screens wider than 1200px, and media means screens between 992px and 1199px. Sizes are documented [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries).)

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eN9qM/5/). Notice that because I didn't specify a `col-sm-X` class, in small screens by default every `li` takes 100% of the width. You can force this by specifying a class for each screen size, if you want. (All this will be much easier to understand once you read the Bootstrap documentation.)

Using Bootstrap you can avoid a lot of media queries and focus in keeping your CSS shorter and clearer.

Comment: That would be great if you could show a bootstrap example. I don't need it now but I was thinking of learning and using bootstrap later. In addition there might be someone else who could use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining how many `<li>`'s in each column, this is quite easy with bootstrap, as follows:

**http://www.bootply.com/bsVWymTjED**

```
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <ul>
      <li>Column 1</li>
      <li>Byebye</li>
      <li>Chuck</li>
      <li>Paul</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <ul>
      <li>Column 2</li>
      <li>Byebye</li>
      <li>Chuck</li>
      <li>Paul</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
  ...
```

<s>But if you're looking for the `<li>`'s to flow from one column to the next, as their number grows, that's another story. Certainly possible, and probably also easy enough, just not at my fingertips...</s>

**EDIT: Scratch that last caveat - second option is also easy, added 2nd answer**

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your `<li>`'s to flow from one column to the next without defining how many in each column, add the col-* classes to the `<li>`'s themselves like so:

```
<ul>
  <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">Hello</li>
  <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">Goodbye</li>
  <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">Chuck</li>
  <li class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">Paul</li>
</ul>
```

**http://www.bootply.com/rr2Qh5K9OF**